log info even when a program is terminated by taskmgr.exe
I'm writing a program in Go and it would be nice to add the "stopping" message to the log file even when the task is killed from the Task Manager, or by executing /taskkill in the console. When testing it, if I press CTRL+C in the VS Code terminal it writes the "stopping" message in the log file, but if I build the exe and then I execute it, it can't write the message when closing or terminating. 
Is there any way to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Since you're managing to write your "stopping message" on some exists, it seems you're already catching some signals (probably using signal.Notify()). Please add that code to the question, that way it will be easier to help you change your code to do what you want.

I'm not 100% sure about MS Windows, but if it operates similar to POSIX signals, then this simply isn't possible. There are signals that can't be intercepted, so you can't log anything in reaction. What you could do though is to run a sidecar process that logs when the main process is terminated. It all depends on what you actually want to achieve.

SIGKILL and SIGINT (Ctrl+C) are two very distinct signals. SIGINT roughly translates to "Hey, process, please shut down gracefully." whereas SIGKILL simply uses OS means to terminate the process no matter what.
